# How to convert UInt8 to Bool in Swift 2

Tags: swift, boolean

I'm having to redo all my code where I was using Boolean that worked in Swift 1.2.  Now in Swift 2.0, I'm using Bool correctly, but I'm unclear how I can convert a UInt8 (0/1) into a Swift Bool.

Example:

```
 let timeDateValid:Bool = bytes[0]
```

**Error Message:**
Cannot Convert Type 'UInt8' to specified type 'Bool'

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try google? Search `UInt8 to Bool in Swift 2`.

Comment: @EvanCarslake sure did, didn't return anything relevant.

Answer (score 5):

Just test if it is  0:

```
let timeDateValid:Bool = (bytes[0] != 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift3**

Convert **UInt8** Byte to **Bool**

```
extension UInt8 {
    func toBool() -> Bool {
        switch self {
        case 0x01:
            return true
        case 0x00:
            return false
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You dont need to return optional Value. It always returns nonoptional. :)

Answer (score 1):

Can be optimized with

```
extension UInt8 {
    func toBool() -> Bool {
        switch self {
        case 0x01:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

or to avoid switch

```
extension UInt8 {
    var toBool: Bool {
        return self == 0x01 ? true : false
    }
}
```